# Console output of an instance

Tags: python, spyder

I just started with object oriented programing in Python and I created a class, now i wrote this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "({0}, {1})".format(self.base, self.error)
```

which works fine if I calculate something in the code e.g.:

```
print R+I
```

the console output is (5.0, 1.0)

I'm working in spyder btw

Now if i type R+I into the console instead it returns 
<**main**.errorCalc instance at 0x0000000009A54F08>

but I'd like it to be shown like this (5.0, 1.0)

any help or ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` command (or function, if Python 3+), looks up and uses `__str__()`. The console generally uses `__repr__()`, which you're also free to define.

Comment: did you redefine repr?

Comment: see my answer...that's what he meant

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry that did the job, I just had a typo Dx thanks so much for your fast support :))

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing `str(R+I)`?

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "({0}, {1})".format(self.base, self.error)
```

Comment: No I hadn't and it works just fine :) Thanks a lot, but l'd prefer a way that I can do this without str(), any ideas?

Comment: well...that's exactly what you said when you did "__str__(self)"  you are telling python that that is the string representation of your class.  " You can also do as the user said above me and override "__repr__".